# C++/CX component "public enum class" Does not link correctly in C# Metro App

Tags: c#, enums, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, c++-cx

i'm trying to wrap D3D11 calls in an API ive been developing.

Ive made a C++/CX component library that i'm trying to use in C#.  This is simple and straightforward if the C++/CX component and C# project are in the SAME solution, everything will work fine...

...but if I create my C++/CX API component in its OWN solution then create a second C# Metro App solution and add my C++/CX component "project" to it and then have my C# Metro App reference the C++/CX component project I get runtime errors when trying to use public enums that were declared in C++.

Here is the public enum class error that my C# app cant seem to link to.

> "Could not find Windows Runtime type
>   'Reign.Video.D3D11.FeatureLevels'."

This is rly frustrating as I can't seem to get my C++/CX "API" stuff to link correctly in a C# app for TESTING.  How are you suppose to productively test an API made in C++ on metro??  You can't link a C++/CX component to a C# project unless there in the same solution and if you try to link the C++/CX project to the C# solution and link it from there you get runtime errors...

**EDIT: Here is a download link of a demo showing my issue:** [Download](http://www.reign-studios.com/Share/MetroDemo.zip)

Comment: Have you tried making the Reign.Video.D3D11.FeatureLevels enum an "enum" instead of a C++0x "enum class"?

Comment: If you do that, the enum will not be exposed to C# at all...  Its must be an "enum class".

Comment: You should run the ildasm tool on the Reign.Video.winmd file that's built with your project. That will show all the classes that are exposed to C#. It's possible that there's info in that which can help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hey tnx for the info about 'ildasm' didn't know that tool existed, very useful.  Although it doesn't rly seem to help me.  It show's that 'FeatureLevels' is in fact being exists and is exposed.

Comment: Hmmm. What's the type of the underlying __value entry?

Comment: "value__ : public specialname rtspecialname int32"   -- If you would like I could make and send a simple solution that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: That would be nice.  That definition should be accepted by C#, a repro solution (as a zip file) would be appreciated. Use the contact info on my blog to send me a link to the zip file.

Comment: Ok I figured that when you use any other namespace other then that of the 'Project Name'... runtime linking does not work correctly.  I'm going to send you a very simple demo for demonstration.

Comment: Ok here is the download link to the demo: http://www.reign-studios.com/Share/MetroDemo.zip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Runtime requires that all types must be found in a namespace that matches the name of the containing .winmd file.  In the demo you linked, your generated winmd is named `ExternalWindowsRuntimeComponentProject.winmd` but your non-working class is found in the `Reign.Video.D3D11` namespace.  This is not permitted by WinRT and the .NET type loader will fail to find types that are not in an associated namespace.

The solution here is to make sure the `FeatureLevels` enum is in a winmd named either `Reign.winmd`, `Reign.Video.winmd`, or `Reign.Video.D3D11.winmd`.

Comment: After what I found I figured as much or there was a bug...  I would recommend MS adding a compile time error for this situation.

Comment: There should be one in the RTM visual studio